# Can't bind cmd+\ to "Move focus to next window", but I can bind it to other actions... why?

Tags: keyboard, macos

I just reinstalled OSX 10.8, and I've encountered an incredibly odd behaviour: binding <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to "Move focus to next window" doesn't work (if I hit it, I get the "pop" error sound). However, binding it to other actions works, and binding other combinations to that action also works.

This makes no sense to me.

I would rather keep using this shortcut, as I'm quite used to it and I hit it often.

Does someone have any clue?

P.S. in case it might help: this *did* work in my previous 10.8 install.

**Update**: doesn't work in 10.10 either: I don't get the "pop" error sound anymore, but it just does nothing.

Comment: What keyboard-layout are you using? It does work on a german keyboard just FYI

Comment: @KevinGrabher I've noticed the German layout has `^` in place of `\\`, so maybe that's why it works? I'm using [a custom-made layout](https://github.com/Lohoris/IT4), but it doesn't work even with plain Italian layout neither with plain Japanese layout, so the layout itself isn't the problem.

Comment: Not a true answer, but might [KeyCue](http://www.ergonis.com/products/keycue/) help? Does using the other Command key have the same effect? If you key Command then use Character Viewer to click the on-screen \ key, does that allow the Command-\ shortcut to used where required?

Answer (score 5):

For what it is worth, I am able to bind <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to **Move Focus to Active or Next Window** in Mavericks, and it works fine for switching between Finder windows.

[image: move focus]

(It doesn't help your situation except to indicate that this might be a bug...)

If you are trying to use it in another application besides the Finder, does the standard <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> work?

I have the **Full Keyboard Access** option below that set to text boxes only:

[image: keyboard access]

EDIT: Reassigning <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> to "Move focus to next window" also works fine for me.

You are probably onto something with the backslash causing the problem, since `defaults write -globalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Move focus to next window" '@\'` gives an error `Could not parse: "@\".  Try single-quoting it.` and trying to escape it with a backslash results in a strange dictionary assignment:

```
$ defaults read -globalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents
{
    "Move focus to next window" = "@\\\\";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work in the Finder either. If I select US layout and set <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> as combination it works, **but** as I said it works anyway with any other combination which isn't that one. "Text boxes" only selected here too.

Comment: The custom layout still seems suspect to me, since it works on other layouts. Command back tick is  a default for window switching in most apps, without any mods. Does that work in your layout before assigning it?

Comment: But as I said it doesn't work in other standard layouts either. It's the backslash who is causing the problems, for some reason. Can I maybe edit the keybindings via text file, just to check they are escaping them correctly?

Comment: I've just noticed: I don't care about "Move focus to active or next window", though it doesn't work either. I care about "Move focus to next window". It's a different command.

Comment: I've run `defaults write -globalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Move focus to next window" "@\\\\"`, and now `defaults read -globalDomain NSUserKeyEquivalents` returns `"Move focus to next window" = "@\\\\";`, but it still doesn't work...